# Yii add text before the value in EColumnsDialog

Tags: php, yii

I have more or less the code in the "view":

```
'columns' => array(
            array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'name' => 'id',
                'value'=>'$data->id',
            ),
```

I need to add to it so that every TEXT id which displays August or early 1,2,3,4,5 was intended "TEXT"
ie no display output in August this:

```
|   ID   |  some_table  |  some_table  |
| TEXT_1 | samplesample | samplesample |
| TEXT_2 | samplesample | samplesample |
| TEXT_3 | samplesample | samplesample |
| TEXT_4 | samplesample | samplesample |
| TEXT_5 | samplesample | samplesample |
```

[image]

Comment: picture shows what I have and what they want to have

http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qdku.png



            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'header' => 'id',
                    'name' => 'id',
                    'value'=>'$data->id',
                ),



I have to do so that the "value => id" instead display an NO.ID Started to display an TXT_ ID NO.ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [YII CGridView error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466683/yii-cgridview-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'header' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'id',
        'value'=>function($data){
            return "TXT".$data->id';
        } 
    ),
```

It's like your other question: [YII CGridView error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466683/yii-cgridview-error)