# YII CGridView error

Tags: php, yii

controller:

```
public function actionItem($textdata){
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Mytest', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                'condition' => 'type="'.$textdata.'"',
            ),
        ));
$bleble = $textdata;
        $this->render('Item', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'bleble' => $bleble,
        ));
    }
```

view:

```
$bleble = $bleble;

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'sample_id',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
                'header' => 'id',
                    'name'   => 'id',
                    'value'  =>'$data->id',
                    'type'   =>'raw',
                    "value"  => function($data){
                        echo "text".$data->id;

                    },
            ),
```

NEED !! :

```
$bleble = $bleble;

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'sample_id',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                    'header' => 'id',
                        'name'   => 'id',
                        'value'  =>'$data->id',
                        'type'   =>'raw',
                        "value"  => function($data){
                            echo $bleble.$data->id;

                        },
                ),
```

error :

PHP notice
Undefined variable: bleble

need to download the text of the link that is how I controller ($ text) $ text is the one I have to write out the table but does not work when it is a variable, normal text works for example echo "text".$data->id;

Comment: still does not work,

"value"  => function($data){
                            echo $bleble.$data->id;

                        },

I need to somehow exchange that is what got the controller for example TEXT shown a way: TEXT_1, TEXT_2, TEXT_3 where the number indicates the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
"value" => function($data) use ($bleble){
    return $bleble.$data->id;
}
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: but as I have that use the?
"value"  => function($data) use $bleble{
    return $bleble.$data->id;
},

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$bleble' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in

Comment: do you have the variable $bleble?

Comment: yes, in controller: $this->render('Item', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'bleble' => $bleble,
        ));


but when before CGridView give echo $bleble; then works

Comment: i found a solution, I edit the answer. I missed the '()' around the '$bleble'.