# Yii EColumnsDialog annother error

Tags: php, yii

```
array(
               'header' => 'checkbox',
               'value' => '(!$data->checkbox_one) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_one", "id" => $data->id)) : ""',
               'type' => 'raw',
               'value'=>function($data){
                   (!$data->checkbox_one) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_one", "id" => $data->id)) : "";
                   (!$data->checkbox_two) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_two", "id" => $data->id)) : "";
               }
           ),
```

needs to display the two or more "checkbox" in one table, normally through the "echo" I am able to display the text like this: [Yii add text before the value in EColumnsDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455075/yii-add-text-before-the-value-in-ecolumnsdialog/26482589#26482589)

and how am I supposed to do with "checkbox"?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an anonymous function you need to return your value:

```
'value' => function($data){
    $result = (!$data->checkbox_one) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_one", "id" => $data->id)) : "";
    echo $result.((!$data->checkbox_two) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_two", "id" => $data->id)) : "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        'value' => function($data){
    $result = (!$data->checkbox_one) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_one", "id" => $data->id)) : "";
$result2 = (!$data->checkbox_two) ? CHtml::checkbox($data->id, false, array("class" => "check_two", "id" => $data->id)) : "";
    echo $result.$result2;

    }
```

works only in this way, but thanks for the answer :)